# t sql concatenate column name and string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using a Case statement within a SELECT query to return a concatenated string.  The string I want to return is a concatenation of a column value and a string specified within the query.

I have pasted the code below, the concatenation part (bold) is shown as if it was in Excel. Please instruct on how this would be done in T SQL.

```
WHEN (InstrumentType = 'Loan' OR InstrumentType = 'LoanF') AND Leg.Principal <0 
THEN CONCATENATE(InstrumentType,' Deposit')
```

Comment: `then InstrumentType + ' Deposit'` if the column is a string else `then cast(InstrumentType as varchar(size_here)) + ' Deposit`

Comment: MSDN reference: [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL Server 2008 something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN InstrumentType IN ('Loan','LoanF') AND Leg.Principal < 0
        THEN InstrumentType + ' Deposit' 
        ELSE 'somethingelse' 
    END AS YourColumn
FROM dbo.Yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
WHEN (InstrumentType = 'Loan' OR InstrumentType = 'LoanF') AND Leg.Principal <0 
THEN InstrumentType+' Deposit'
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is available only in SQL Server 2012. The OP mentioned using 2008 version.